# Use part of CSS-Sprite as repeated background image

Tags: css, web-component, css-sprites, background-position

I have a `div` with a width and height of approximately `300px` each. The background of this `div` should be filled repeatedly with a smaller image of 8px width and `8px` height. This smaller image is embedded into a larger sprite image. How can I only use this `8x8` pixel tile to pave the background?

What I've tried so far:

```css
.world {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAIAAABvFaqvAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH4wcYFjsX3EPV0QAAAB1pVFh0Q29tbWVudAAAAAAAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBkLmUHAAAAxklEQVQ4y+2UsQ3CMBBF/0VImYDKFWNQZB28AwOwQ7KOC8agomKCVJ8ituU7GwkhVxFXWT+nF8nvy0JSRFAMye0wqRghxrheTmV+Wx4A9G7BmlpfAi0lswZ0mj2DsiNjLbBx09lRw1oN+m0OAKB7hIQWvFSM43ZY5V7mI88AhB+KZCiZZSiZ9e/RN6BaP1k6MtY2Ry1rPXv01D1yET3qR2ZF+qXX+zMBDJaSuGP1VMXEV/te9q6/G8hV+h2VI2NtrvZn9uzRGzl9Uzsn2uDrAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') 0 -16px repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="world"></div>
```

In this example code, the shritesheet has a width and height of `24px` each. It contains 9 differently coloured points, each of which has a diameter of `7px`.

I want that only one single point is used repeatedly as background for the div. However, in this code, the whole picture is repeated instead beginning at the third row of points.

> *Note, this exemplary spritesheet is only an example. The actual spritesheet is a little more complicated. Replacing the spritesheet
>   with CSS code is not a solution.*

Comment: there is no trivial solution to do this but since they are simple coloured points why not using a radial-gradient that you repeat?

Comment: Unfortunately, the actual spritesheet is a little more complicated than just dots. Those were just an example. `radial-gradient` is therefore no solution to the actual problem.

Comment: basically you cannot, CSS doesn't allow you to cut an image and repeat it as pattern unless we consider some hacks to approximate this

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks. So, I'll need to use a dedicated spritesheet only for the background that contains only the 8x8 pixel square.

Comment: are you open to SVG? I guess it's doable with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to consider SVG as background. The trick is to make the image inside the SVG and rely on viewbox to cut the image and show only the needed part then make the whole SVG a pattern for your background.

Simply edit the `viewBox` to select the pattern you want (`x y 8 8` where `x,y` are equal to `[0,8,16]`)

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.one {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="16 0 8 8" width="8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAIAAABvFaqvAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH4wcYFjsX3EPV0QAAAB1pVFh0Q29tbWVudAAAAAAAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBkLmUHAAAAxklEQVQ4y+2UsQ3CMBBF/0VImYDKFWNQZB28AwOwQ7KOC8agomKCVJ8ituU7GwkhVxFXWT+nF8nvy0JSRFAMye0wqRghxrheTmV+Wx4A9G7BmlpfAi0lswZ0mj2DsiNjLbBx09lRw1oN+m0OAKB7hIQWvFSM43ZY5V7mI88AhB+KZCiZZSiZ9e/RN6BaP1k6MtY2Ry1rPXv01D1yET3qR2ZF+qXX+zMBDJaSuGP1VMXEV/te9q6/G8hV+h2VI2NtrvZn9uzRGzl9Uzsn2uDrAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" x="0" y="0" height="24" width="24" /></svg>')  repeat;
}
.two {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="16 8 8 8" width="8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAIAAABvFaqvAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH4wcYFjsX3EPV0QAAAB1pVFh0Q29tbWVudAAAAAAAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBkLmUHAAAAxklEQVQ4y+2UsQ3CMBBF/0VImYDKFWNQZB28AwOwQ7KOC8agomKCVJ8ituU7GwkhVxFXWT+nF8nvy0JSRFAMye0wqRghxrheTmV+Wx4A9G7BmlpfAi0lswZ0mj2DsiNjLbBx09lRw1oN+m0OAKB7hIQWvFSM43ZY5V7mI88AhB+KZCiZZSiZ9e/RN6BaP1k6MtY2Ry1rPXv01D1yET3qR2ZF+qXX+zMBDJaSuGP1VMXEV/te9q6/G8hV+h2VI2NtrvZn9uzRGzl9Uzsn2uDrAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" x="0" y="0" height="24" width="24" /></svg>')  repeat;
}

.three {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="8 0 8 8" width="8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAIAAABvFaqvAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH4wcYFjsX3EPV0QAAAB1pVFh0Q29tbWVudAAAAAAAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBkLmUHAAAAxklEQVQ4y+2UsQ3CMBBF/0VImYDKFWNQZB28AwOwQ7KOC8agomKCVJ8ituU7GwkhVxFXWT+nF8nvy0JSRFAMye0wqRghxrheTmV+Wx4A9G7BmlpfAi0lswZ0mj2DsiNjLbBx09lRw1oN+m0OAKB7hIQWvFSM43ZY5V7mI88AhB+KZCiZZSiZ9e/RN6BaP1k6MtY2Ry1rPXv01D1yET3qR2ZF+qXX+zMBDJaSuGP1VMXEV/te9q6/G8hV+h2VI2NtrvZn9uzRGzl9Uzsn2uDrAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" x="0" y="0" height="24" width="24" /></svg>')  repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box one"></div>

<div class="box two"></div>

<div class="box three"></div>
```

Comment: Some tips for when you are going to generate this with JS (I used SVG in data-uris heavly in Custom Elements [PlayingCardts](https://card-ts.github.io/playingcardts) and [Chessly](https://chessly.github.io) ) ► replace doublequotes in the SVG with single quotes, built strings as ` ` (template literal strings) because at some point you (may) need that double quote for other purposes. And you can save bytes on ``xlink:href`` with just ``href`` see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href) HTH

Comment: This is a very interesting suggestion! Thank you! :)